# Finite Content Not Continuous on the Empty Set

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I have come across a lemma which states:

Let $\mu$ be a finite content on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$.
$\mu$ is a pre-measure if and only if $\mu$ is continuous on the empty set, i.e., for every sequence $(A_i)_{i \geq 1}$ from $\mathcal{A}$ with $A_i \downarrow \emptyset$, we have $\mu(A_i) \rightarrow 0$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$.

Could someone provide an example of a finite content $\mu$ that is not continuous on the empty set?

Comment: What's a content?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: finitely additive measure.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In addition to the comment from Chad: a content is defined for algebras and not only for $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I've never heard it referred to as a content before.

Comment: @SineOfTheTimes: See the edit, by limiting the algebra, free ultrafilters are not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb{N}$.  There is an associated finitely-additive measure $\mu_\mathcal{U}$ on subsets of $\Bbb{N}$ such that $\mu_\mathcal{U}(S)=1$ for $S\in\mathcal{U}$ and $\mu_\mathcal{U}(S)=0$ for $S\not\in\mathcal{U}$.

Let $A_n=\Bbb{N}\setminus\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$.  Then $\mu_\mathcal{U}(A_n)=1$ but $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb{N}} A_n = \emptyset$.

If you're not working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, it's possible for there to be no free ultrafilters on $\Bbb{N}$.  For a finitely-additive finite measure to be discontinuous at $\emptyset$, it must be defined on an infinite set.  The space of finitely-additive finite measures defined for all subsets of $\Bbb{N}$ is the (Banach space) dual of $\ell^\infty(\Bbb{N})$.  In $\mathsf{ZF}$ it's possible the dual of $\ell^\infty(\Bbb{N})$ reduces to $\ell^1(\Bbb{N})$.  The members of $\ell^1(\Bbb{N})$, interpreted as measures on $\Bbb{N}$ are all $\sigma$-additive so are continuous at $\emptyset$.

Since $\mu$ is not required to be defined for all subsets of $\Bbb{N}$, you can take the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ to be the algebra consisting of all finite or co-finite subsets of $\Bbb{N}$.  Define $\mu(S)=1$ for $S$ co-finite and $\mu(S)=0$ for $S$ finite and you get the same example, but no need for free ultrafilters.

Comment: Hahn–Banach is enough to prove $\ell^1$ is not reflexive, but it is not enough to prove there are free ultrafilters on the naturals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: fixed.